# Thingspeak : Updating chart options with API, Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm working on an IoT project and I need to create a channel on Thingspeak using HTTP or MQTT methods. I managed to create the channel, but I don't know how to set the charts with the options that I want.

Python code:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json', data = {"api_key":"XXXXXXX", "name":"Silvia", "field1":"1", "field2": "2"}) # I create the channel with 2 charts
r1 = requests.put('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1053983.json', data = {"api_key":XXXXXX", "field1":"fff", "field2": "stcc"}) # changing the name of the charts
```

1. How can I set chart 1 option "average" to daily?
2. How can I set the status of the channel to true? (The channel should show its status)